# Search engine to find all prior patents of patent attorney

Tags: uspto, search, epo, attorney

Do you know a US / EU search engine where you can type in a patent attorney name and then find all patents and customers who he/she released patents with?

Answer (score 2):

For the U.S. you can go to its [patent search page](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=0&f=S&l=50&d=PTXT&RS=LREP%2F%28%22George%22%20AND%20%22White%22%29&Refine=Refine%20Search&Query=LREP%2F%28%22White%3B%20George%22%29) and search for Legal Representative (LREP). I tried it with my first name last name, got 0 hits; first name middle initial last name, got 0 hits. Then I tried LREP/("George" AND "White") which would hit if anyone had my first name anywhere in their name AND also had my last name anywhere in their name. I got 50 hits and saw the name format used - last name; first name - maybe middle initial. Using that LREP/("White; George") I got the same 50 hits, as it happens.

A big caveat is many firms put the firm name on the issue fee payment form rather than the specific practitioner's name.  I just looked up a mentor of mine who must have several hundred patents granted and it comes up zero. The information is not secret, the actual filings in every case ( individually available at [Public PAIR](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair)) must be signed by an actual person who also puts down their registration number.